# NEXTJS api + axios + NextAuth issue : AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios, next-auth

I have a basic Next.js application, in which
I'm want to use NextAuth for authentication purpose for which I need axios to make calls to the api folder in the same nextjs app. I'm using credentials provider in it.

```
authorize: async (credentials, req) => {
....
const verify_url = "http://localhost:3000" + "/api/verify";
console.log("starting fetch", axios.get(verify_url))
....}
```

If I change the verify_url to the following (http://127.0.0.1:3000) then there is not error in axios, and app works fine.

```
const verify_url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000" + "/api/verify";
```

this api is present in the same nextjs app at http://localhost:3000/api/verify
The app is running perfectly when in dev mode, but after build and start it's showing following error.

getting following error in axios when making requests:

```
file:///D:/projects/xyz/testnextauth/node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:89
  AxiosError.call(axiosError, error.message, code, config, request, response);
             ^
AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
    at AxiosError.from (file:///D:/projects/xyz/testnextauth/node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:89:14)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (file:///D:/projects/xyz/testnextauth/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:577:25)    
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at eventHandlers.<computed> (D:\projects\xyz\testnextauth\node_modules\follow-redirects\index.js:14:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  port: 3000,
  address: '::1',
  syscall: 'connect',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: -4078,
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: {
      FormData: [Function: FormData] {
        LINE_BREAK: '\r\n',
        DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/octet-stream'
      },
      Blob: [class Blob]
    },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: AxiosHeaders {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.3.4',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/verify',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *2> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError],
      socket: [Function: handleRequestSocket]
    },
    _eventsCount: 3,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: '/api/verify',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object: null prototype] {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/1.3.4',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
      },
      agents: { http: undefined, https: undefined },
      auth: undefined,
      beforeRedirect: [Function: dispatchBeforeRedirect],
      beforeRedirects: { proxy: [Function: beforeRedirect] },
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: '3000',
      agent: undefined,
      nativeProtocols: {
        'http:': {
          _connectionListener: [Function: connectionListener],
          METHODS: [
            'ACL',         'BIND',       'CHECKOUT',
            'CONNECT',     'COPY',       'DELETE',
            'GET',         'HEAD',       'LINK',
            'LOCK',        'M-SEARCH',   'MERGE',
            'MKACTIVITY',  'MKCALENDAR', 'MKCOL',
            'MOVE',        'NOTIFY',     'OPTIONS',
            'PATCH',       'POST',       'PROPFIND',
            'PROPPATCH',   'PURGE',      'PUT',
            'REBIND',      'REPORT',     'SEARCH',
            'SOURCE',      'SUBSCRIBE',  'TRACE',
            'UNBIND',      'UNLINK',     'UNLOCK',
            'UNSUBSCRIBE'
          ],
          STATUS_CODES: {
            '100': 'Continue',
            '101': 'Switching Protocols',
            '102': 'Processing',
            '103': 'Early Hints',
            '200': 'OK',
            '201': 'Created',
            '202': 'Accepted',
            '203': 'Non-Authoritative Information',
            '204': 'No Content',
            '205': 'Reset Content',
            '206': 'Partial Content',
            '207': 'Multi-Status',
            '208': 'Already Reported',
            '226': 'IM Used',
            '300': 'Multiple Choices',
            '301': 'Moved Permanently',
            '302': 'Found',
            '303': 'See Other',
            '304': 'Not Modified',
            '305': 'Use Proxy',
            '307': 'Temporary Redirect',
            '308': 'Permanent Redirect',
            '400': 'Bad Request',
            '401': 'Unauthorized',
            '402': 'Payment Required',
            '403': 'Forbidden',
            '404': 'Not Found',
            '405': 'Method Not Allowed',
            '406': 'Not Acceptable',
            '407': 'Proxy Authentication Required',
            '408': 'Request Timeout',
            '409': 'Conflict',
            '410': 'Gone',
            '411': 'Length Required',
            '412': 'Precondition Failed',
            '413': 'Payload Too Large',
            '414': 'URI Too Long',
            '415': 'Unsupported Media Type',
            '416': 'Range Not Satisfiable',
            '417': 'Expectation Failed',
            '418': "I'm a Teapot",
            '421': 'Misdirected Request',
            '422': 'Unprocessable Entity',
            '423': 'Locked',
            '424': 'Failed Dependency',
            '425': 'Too Early',
            '426': 'Upgrade Required',
            '428': 'Precondition Required',
            '429': 'Too Many Requests',
            '431': 'Request Header Fields Too Large',
            '451': 'Unavailable For Legal Reasons',
            '500': 'Internal Server Error',
            '501': 'Not Implemented',
            '502': 'Bad Gateway',
            '503': 'Service Unavailable',
            '504': 'Gateway Timeout',
            '505': 'HTTP Version Not Supported',
            '506': 'Variant Also Negotiates',
            '507': 'Insufficient Storage',
            '508': 'Loop Detected',
            '509': 'Bandwidth Limit Exceeded',
            '510': 'Not Extended',
            '511': 'Network Authentication Required'
          },
          Agent: [Function: Agent] { defaultMaxSockets: Infinity },
          ClientRequest: [Function: ClientRequest],
          IncomingMessage: [Function: IncomingMessage],
          OutgoingMessage: [Function: OutgoingMessage],
          Server: [Function: Server],
          ServerResponse: [Function: ServerResponse],
          createServer: [Function: createServer],
          validateHeaderName: [Function: __node_internal_],
          validateHeaderValue: [Function: __node_internal_],
          get: [Function: get],
          request: [Function: request],
          setMaxIdleHTTPParsers: [Function: setMaxIdleHTTPParsers],
          maxHeaderSize: [Getter],
          globalAgent: [Getter/Setter]
        },
        'https:': {
          Agent: [Function: Agent],
          globalAgent: Agent {
            _events: [Object: null prototype],
            _eventsCount: 2,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            defaultPort: 443,
            protocol: 'https:',
            options: [Object: null prototype],
            requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
            sockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
            freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
            keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
            keepAlive: false,
            maxSockets: Infinity,
            maxFreeSockets: 256,
            scheduling: 'lifo',
            maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
            totalSocketCount: 0,
            maxCachedSessions: 100,
            _sessionCache: [Object],
            [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
          },
          Server: [Function: Server],
          createServer: [Function: createServer],
          get: [Function: get],
          request: [Function: request]
        }
      },
      pathname: '/api/verify'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {
        response: [Function: bound onceWrapper] {
          listener: [Function (anonymous)]
        },
        abort: [Function (anonymous)],
        aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
        connect: [Function (anonymous)],
        error: [Function (anonymous)],
        socket: [Function (anonymous)],
        timeout: [Function (anonymous)]
      },
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: true,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'localhost',
        _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
        _readableState: ReadableState {
          objectMode: false,
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
          length: 0,
          pipes: [],
          flowing: true,
          ended: false,
          endEmitted: false,
          reading: true,
          constructed: true,
          sync: false,
          needReadable: true,
          emittedReadable: false,
          readableListening: false,
          resumeScheduled: false,
          errorEmitted: true,
          emitClose: false,
          autoDestroy: true,
          destroyed: true,
          errored: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 3000
          },
          closed: true,
          closeEmitted: true,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          awaitDrainWriters: null,
          multiAwaitDrain: false,
          readingMore: false,
          dataEmitted: false,
          decoder: null,
          encoding: null,
          [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
        },
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          end: [Function: onReadableStreamEnd],
          connect: [ [Function], [Function], [Function] ],
          free: [Function: onFree],
          close: [ [Function: onClose], [Function: socketCloseListener] ],
          timeout: [Function: onTimeout],
          agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
          error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
          drain: [Function: ondrain]
        },
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: WritableState {
          objectMode: false,
          highWaterMark: 16384,
          finalCalled: false,
          needDrain: false,
          ending: false,
          ended: false,
          finished: false,
          destroyed: true,
          decodeStrings: false,
          defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
          length: 183,
          writing: true,
          corked: 0,
          sync: false,
          bufferProcessing: false,
          onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
          writecb: [Function: bound onFinish],
          writelen: 183,
          afterWriteTickInfo: null,
          buffered: [],
          bufferedIndex: 0,
          allBuffers: true,
          allNoop: true,
          pendingcb: 1,
          constructed: true,
          prefinished: false,
          errorEmitted: true,
          emitClose: false,
          autoDestroy: true,
          errored: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 3000
          },
          closed: true,
          closeEmitted: true,
          [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
        },
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: 'GET /api/verify HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
          'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
          'User-Agent: axios/1.3.4\r\n' +
          'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
          'Host: localhost:3000\r\n' +
          'Connection: close\r\n' +
          '\r\n',
        _pendingEncoding: 'latin1',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
        [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 387,
        [Symbol(kHandle)]: null,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
        [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
        [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
      },
      _header: 'GET /api/verify HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.3.4\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost:3000\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: Agent {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          free: [Function (anonymous)],
          newListener: [Function: maybeEnableKeylog]
        },
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 80,
        protocol: 'http:',
        options: [Object: null prototype] { noDelay: true, path: null },
        requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
        sockets: [Object: null prototype] {
          'localhost:3000:': [ [Socket], [Socket] ]
        },
        freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        scheduling: 'lifo',
        maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
        totalSocketCount: 2,
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
      },
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/api/verify',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *2],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
        accept: [ 'Accept', 'application/json, text/plain, */*' ],
        'user-agent': [ 'User-Agent', 'axios/1.3.4' ],
        'accept-encoding': [ 'Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, compress, deflate, br' ],
        host: [ 'Host', 'localhost:3000' ]
      },
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/verify',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
    errno: -4078,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 3000
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the issue is related to ipv4 vs ipv6 resolution between binding and connecting.

(i.e. Next.js is bound on ipv4 but "localhost" is resolved to ipv6 address)

I had similar issues in Node v18, waiting for the "happy eyeballs" fix to be enabled via config which apparently will be in Node v20

https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/44731

To avoid issues across multiple different packages I downgraded to node v16.

Comment: I lost hope on this issue

Comment: Just downgrade node < 17, or disable ipv6

Comment: But won't this create issues in production?

Comment: upgrading to node v20 did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and thankfully the answer from @craigw helped find a solution after countless hours.

In case anybody else faces the same issue, and is using MAC, simply commenting out the ipv6 localhost from the /private/etc/hosts file does the trick:

```
#::1             localhost
127.0.0.1     localhost
```

If you don't want to comment it out I think placing it below the ipv4 line should also do the trick. From what I gather it seems axios coupled with next finds the first localhost entry in the hosts file and uses that.