Nextjs connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000 during fetching data in server side Component
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

interface UsersType {
id: string;
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
email: string;
}
interface dataProps {
 allUsers: UsersType[];
}

 async function getData() {


   try {
    const { data } = await axios.get<dataProps>(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WAITINGLIST_URL}/waitinglist/`
    );

      // console.log(data);

    return data;
   } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
   }


      }

  export default async function Page() {
   const data = await getData();
   // console.log(data?.allUsers);

   return (
     <div className="text-white w-100">
     <table className="w-full table  ">
        <thead>
         <tr className=" [&>th]:text-center [&>th]:py-3 [&>th]:px-2 ">
           <th>First Name</th>
           <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          {data?.allUsers?.map((item: UsersType) => {
        return (
          <tr
            key={item?.id}
            className=" [&>td]:text-center [&>td]:py-3 [&>td]:px-2 "
          >
            <td>{item?.firstName}</td>
            <td>{item?.lastName}</td>
            <td>{item?.email}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

);
}

Build Time Error on Console

[Error]: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
at I.from (E:\usman data\maincorenextjs.next\server\app\dashboard\admin\page.js:11:10985)
at y. (E:\usman data\maincorenextjs.next\server\app\dashboard\admin\page.js:13:21276) {
port: 3000,
address: '::1',
syscall: 'connect',
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
errno: -4078,
method: 'get',
url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/waitinglist/',
data: undefined
},

.env file

NEXT_PUBLIC_WAITINGLIST_URL="http://localhost:3000/api"

versions

** Node ** : * 18.18.1 *
** Nextjs ** : * 14.2.1 *

I have seen that but it is of no beneficial to me.

on second thought it was beneficial. nextjs uses ipv4 and localhost resolved to ipv6. so that is causing the issue.

Great! I'll post as the answer then and you can mark this as accepted.

Try renaming NEXT_PUBLIC_WAITINGLIST_URL to WAITINGLIST_URL.
If your env variables start with NEXT_PUBLIC prefix, it will be accessed by the browser not server and you're in a server component.
You can refer to https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser

Yes it is the way for environment variables to be used. in the client side you have NEXT_PUBLIC prefix and for server side a simple env variable is enough Ie, WAITINGLIST_URL.
but this did not solve my problem. from my research that is an issue with nextjs. my code is build at the end and can published on server and will work.  but again why this happens???

also if I use the simple fetch function from js it still gives long error.

Looks like it has to do with ipv4 vs ipv6 resolution, answered previously here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75842143/9985521
